# ProcessPoolExecutor Workers Have Same "Thread ID"?

Tags: python, multithreading

Was looking at the thread ids while using a multiprocessor pool and noticed they all have the same thread id but different process ids. When using a threadpool the workers have different thread ids but the same process id (as expected), but I didn't expect in a process pool that all the workers would have the same thread id.

```
def identify_self():
    import threading
    import os
    import time

    time.sleep(random())
    print(f"Thread={threading.get_ident()}, Process={os.getpid()}")
    time.sleep(3)


print("MP:")
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for i in range(10):
        executor.submit(identify_self)


print("MT:")
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for i in range(10):
        executor.submit(identify_self)
```

Output:

```
MP:
Thread=4584541632, Process=56989
Thread=4584541632, Process=56996
Thread=4584541632, Process=56998
Thread=4584541632, Process=56993
Thread=4584541632, Process=56990
Thread=4584541632, Process=56991
Thread=4584541632, Process=56992
Thread=4584541632, Process=56995
Thread=4584541632, Process=56997
Thread=4584541632, Process=56994
MT:
Thread=123145380663296, Process=56985
Thread=123145427959808, Process=56985
Thread=123145396428800, Process=56985
Thread=123145391173632, Process=56985
Thread=123145401683968, Process=56985
Thread=123145406939136, Process=56985
Thread=123145422704640, Process=56985
Thread=123145385918464, Process=56985
Thread=123145417449472, Process=56985
Thread=123145412194304, Process=56985
```

What does it mean when processpool workers have the same threadid? Does it have an affect on the GIL at all?

Comment: The GIL is only a factor within an individual process. In multiprocessing with a single thread per process, the GIL is not an an issue.

Comment: Which operating system? Each process has its own virtual memory space and its own GIL, so they do not interfere. Not that things can't get funky.

Comment: You're doing multiprocessing (separate processes) not multithreading (separate threads). See [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) if you want to do the latter (where the GIL might be an issue).

Comment: @tdelaney: "Funky" — a technical term?

Comment: (1) Why not post a script that works, and (2) let us know which operating sytem you are on. I'm sure its a forking OS like linux, but still, linux and windows work differently (fork verses spawn) and that makes a difference.

Comment: On a forking OS, the new process is created with `fork` - after the fork the parent and the child still have the same thread id (its the same memory space after all) but different pids. All objects alive in the parent are alive in the child. It can get weird if you interact with a different copy of the same object in each subprocess if that object has some effect on the outside world (maybe wrting the same file, unlocking a file system semaphore, using a socket).